# Помогите , пожалуйста. По какой то причин вместо того что бы выводить строки по возрастанию 0 в строке ,он меняет символы матрицы. Код и задание:

Tags: c, матрицы

Задание:Упорядочить содержащие нули строки матрицы S(n, m) в порядке возрастания их количества. Код конечно сортирует ,но мне не нужно менять елементы матрицы.Думаю ошибка в этой части. Допустим на входе матрица 2*3:
1 2 0.
2 3 4.
На выходе:
1 0 0.
0 0 -1. Ожидаю:
2 3 4.
1 2 0.
То есть она отсортировали по возрастанию ,но и почему то поменяла елементы

```
  double arr_S[100][100]; //двовимірний масив 
  int n; //кількість рядків  
  int m; //кількість стовпців 
  int i,j;
  int k[n];
  k[n] = 0 ;
  
  
for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
        for( j = 0 ; j < m ; j++ )if(arr_S[i][j]==0)k[i]++;
 
for( i = 0 ; i < n -1 ; i++ )
      for( j = i + 1 ; j < m ; j++)
          if(k[j]<k[i]){   
          int tmp = k[i];
          k[i]=k[j];
          k[j] = tmp;
          int p;
          for( p = 0 ; p < m ; p++ ){
          tmp = arr_S[i][p];
          arr_S[i][p]=arr_S[j][p];
          arr_S[j][p]=tmp;
          }
        
    }
 
for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ){
for ( j = 0 ; j < m ; j++)
  printf("%d ", arr_S[i][j]);  
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135981/discussion-on-question-by-inna-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код не должен выдавать ошибок

```
double arr_S[100][100]; 
  int n=2; //lines
  int m; //columns
  int i,j;
  int k[2]={};
```